# Implement RecyclerView with CardView and GridView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridview, android-cardview

Im trying to implement a RecyclingView that contains a CardView which contains a GridView. Not getting any errors just nothing is showing. Just a white screen when I try to run the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView mWeatherTemp, mWeatherDescript;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    Context context;
    GridView gridView;
    String[] mTime = {
            "1:00",
            "2:00",
            "3:00",
            "4:00",
            "5:00",
            "6:00",
            "7:00",
            "8:00",
            "9:00",
            "10:00",
            "11:00",

    };

    String[] mDegreeTemp = {
            "8°",
            "12°",
            "43°",
            "100°",
            "32°",
            "12°",
            "58°",
            "39°",
            "29°",
            "86°",
            "70°",

    };

    int[] imageId = {
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher
    };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mMainToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.weather_cool));

        mWeatherTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWeatherTemp);
        mWeatherDescript = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWeatherText);

        Typeface robotDisplay3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                "font/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        mWeatherTemp.setTypeface(robotDisplay3);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mHourlyRV);
        HourlyGridAdapter adapter = new HourlyGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mTime, mDegreeTemp, imageId);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.hourlyGridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}


public class HourlyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mTime;
    private String[] mDegreeTemp;
    private final int[] imageId;

    public HourlyGridAdapter(Context context, String[] mTime, String[] mDegreeTemp, int[] imageId) {
        mContext = context;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.mDegreeTemp = mDegreeTemp;
        this.mTime = mTime;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hourly_single, null, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.timeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timePlaceHolder);
            holder.degreeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.degreePlaceHolder);
            holder.weatherImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.weatherIconHolder);

            holder.timeText.setText(mTime[position]);
            holder.degreeText.setText(mDegreeTemp[position]);
            holder.weatherImage.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView timeText, degreeText;
        ImageView weatherImage;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TODAY" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/forecast_card_divider" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/hourlyGridView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="12dp"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:verticalSpacing="12dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timePlaceHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/timePlaceHolderText"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weatherIconHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/degreePlaceHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12°"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Im not even sure if having a GridView inside a CardView all inside a recycled view is possible. Any help trying to create this would be creately appreicated.

PS. I know im not calling recyclerView thats declared as that doesnt work and does crash the app and the GridView is null. Not really sure what to do here. Not sure if I need to create an adapter for the recyclerview as all the textViews and ImageView is in the grid not the cardview.

Comment: There is no layout manager or adapter for your recycler view. You need to have both in order for anything to show up in the recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing and setting adapter for gridview which is inside each item of recyclerview not in recycler adapter but in activity. Consider removing all gridview-related code to recyclerview's adapter.